# include ::before pseudo class in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Why is this thing not working? If I remove ::before from javascript and css it works. But due to the design needs there has to be a ::before. How do I point to the class + ::before?

```
$(function () {



var sections = $("section");
var navigation_links = $("nav a");

sections.waypoint({
    handler: function (event, direction) {

        var active_section;
        active_section = $(this);
        if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();

        var active_link = $('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
        navigation_links.removeClass("selected::before");
        active_link.addClass("selected::before");

    },
    offset: '25%'
})
```

});

css:

```
.selected::before {
display: block;
content: "";
margin-top: 6px;
width: 8px;
height: 8px;
background: url(../img/sprite.png) -126px -196px;
background-size: 400px 480px;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
```

}

Comment: `.selected::before` is a selector, not a class, so you can't use that as an argument to `removeClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the `::before` in the JS. As long as the `.selected` class appears on the element, CSS will do the rest. `addClass("selected::before")` is telling the browser to add a class called "selected::before", which is not what you want. (I'm not even sure you are allowed to have `::` in a class name, but I suspect not.)

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I did remove the extra : from :: and it just works. Long hours, I'm mainly a designer, and it's my first try at coding my own website. So, I thank you sir for your help!

Comment: @ralph.m The :: is a pseudo-element selector and is completely valid. But yes, user just needs to reference the class, not with the pseudo-element attached. And user, : and :: is the same for ::before. :: is proper, but : does the same thing because some browsers initially supported it that way.

Comment: @niko in my logic I honestly thought that : and :: are used when you have a situation like .class:hover::before but yeah, it works with single : as well.

Comment: @niko—I just meant using the characters `:` or `::` within a class name, rather than as a pseudo-element. I know these days a lot more characters are allowed in class names, though. According to this link, it apparently *is* valid to use colons in a class name these days: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/crazy-class